# Get the length of List that exists in Map<String,List<Object>> in Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, listview, dart

so i'm working on a Map that has this structure :

```
Map<String, List<Video>> mapName;
```

Where Video is just an object that has 3 attributes : String title,String videoURL, bool isDone.

I'm planing on creating a listView that will display all Video titles so i'm just trying to figure out how to get the length of the list that exists into the Map.

I tryed some test and it displayed this :

```
print(videoList.values.map((list) => list.length));

    I/flutter (23887): (9)
```

Now its true that i have 9 videos in the list, but I cannot use this in my listview itemcount because it requires an int type data.

Comment: what do you wanna achieve with this print(videoList.values.map((list) => list.length));

Answer (score 0):

If your Map have more than one list of videos by the key String of the Map, you can get all lengths using this code:

```
Map<String, List<Video>> mapName = {
  'video1': [Video(),Video()],
  'video2': [Video()],
  'video3': [Video(),Video(),Video()],
}; //Init

int total = 0;
  
mapName.keys.forEach((key){
  List<Video> video = mapName[key];
  int length = video.length;
  print('$key: $length');
  total += length;
});
  
print('total: $total');
```

[image]

Flutter Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class Video {
  final String name;
  final String url;
  final bool isDone;

  Video(this.name, this.url, this.isDone);
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Map<String, List<Video>> mapName = {
      'video1': [
        Video('Bunny', 'http://????', false),
        Video('Bunny10', 'http://????', true),
      ],
      'video2': [
        Video('Bunny2', 'http://????', false),
      ],
      'video3': [
        Video('BunnyX', 'http://????', false),
        Video('Bunny12', 'http://????', true),
        Video('BunnyZZ', 'http://????', false),
      ],
    }; //Init

    List<Video> mVideos = [];

    mapName.values.forEach((videos) {
      videos.forEach((video) {
        mVideos.add(video);
      });
    });

    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: mVideos.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            Video video = mVideos[index];

            String name = video.name;
            String url = video.url;
            bool isDone = video.isDone;

            return ListTile(
              tileColor: isDone ? Colors.green : null,
              title: Text(name),
              subtitle: Text(url),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('Hello, World!', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The example in flutter is in the answer